# CSS Transition Sends Div Below Content on :hover exit

Tags: css, css-position, css-animations

I have the css transition working when the user hovers over `item` however when the mouse exits the `div`, content is pushed below during the transition. Below is my html/css along with a jsfiddle to show what I mean.

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
        </div>
        <div class="heading">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.img {
    background: #000;
    width: 40%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.heading {
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
    float: right;
    background: #900;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.item:hover .img {
    width: 100%;
}

.item:hover .heading {
    width: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1Ln1seef/17/)

I am sure it is a simple `position` problem. However, I am not familiar enough with the `transition` to know where to find the answer.

**Updated** `position` to

```
tranform: translateY(-100%);
```

in order to get rid of the non-transition property. Now before/after `:hover` the `div` `heading` gets pushed below `item`. Updated JSFiddle to show.

**Updated** `transition: all` to `transition: width` on both `img` and `heading` which fixed `heading` getting pushed below `img` on `:hover`, however the original problem of `heading` being pushed below when user exits `:hover` is still an issue.

Comment: do you want the transition to happen while you exit the div too?....but stay in that location instead of below?

Comment: @Phani, I want it to transition back into 40/60 split without it moving outside of the `item` div. Basically, I want the opposite reaction to :hover when they exit the div.

Comment: You can't transition `position`...Hey, that rhymes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think I found the answer**:

by making `heading` have `position:absolute;`, I can have it forced to stay inside of the `item` `div`, keeping it from moving below it. So my updated css (with actual `class` names and production stuff) looks like;

```
.flight {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;

}

.flight-img {
    background: red;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

    /* CSS Animation Effects */
    transition: width 0.5s ease;

}


.flight-heading {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

/* Alternate img float ***
/* Probably an easier way but this works for now */
.flight:nth-of-type(4n-1) .flight-img{
float: right;
}
.flight:nth-of-type(4n-3) .flight-img{
    float: left;
}
.flight:nth-of-type(4n-1) .flight-heading{
    left:0;
}
.flight:nth-of-type(4n-3) .flight-heading{
    float: right;
}

/* Adding hover effects for desktop */

.flight:hover .flight-img {
    width: 100%;
}

.flight:hover .flight-heading {
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    color: #fff;

    h2 {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

while my html looks like:

```
<div id="flights">
    <div class="flight">
        <div class="flight-img"></div>
        <div class="flight-heading">
            <h2>Shared Flights</h2>
            <p>The shared flight option is available for 1 to 5 people. This is our most economical flight. You will fly with other passengers that are booked that day.</p>
            <button>Book Now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!-- End Flights -->
```

with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc4ekwqv/1/) to show. I know the animation needs work, but I figure making it smooth will be easy now that the `divs` stay in one place.